# Asp.net 4.7 Project not loading in VS 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I am struggling with understanding why my legacy .csproj doesn't get loaded in Visual Studio 2022.

I have solution with 100 csprojects, all of them target .NET 4.7, two of the projects are asp.net webforms/webservice projects.

Everything is fine and working on Visual Studio 2019 on Win10.

I have issues with 2019 studio performance and decided to try Visual Studio 2022, installed it on the same machine, and when opening the solution, all of the projects load except one which is asp.net project - it doesn't load. When trying to reload I receive:

[image]

[image]

and unfortunately nothing more.

I am curious in finding why this happens, but the error itself doesn't give enough information to find something.
What I was able to find that this might be some COM component issue, but thats all.

Can someone give some ideas on how to proceed with this?
running devenv with /Log flag doesn't show any description of loading project error.

Comment: Well, I would open that one offending project in vs2022, and see if you can build it. I mean, a 100 projects in one? Gee, I have to wonder if that is a good idea here? Anyway, the other issue is what CPU are you using here? x86, x64, or ANY? Remember, vs2022 is the FIRST version of vs that is x64 bits. So, when you hit f5 to run with vs2019, then you get a x32 bit in-process running of that system (assuming ANY CPU). With vs2022, you hit f5 to run the project, you get a x64 bit version of that project running. So, use of "any" CPU can and will matter here since vs2019 is x32 and 22 is x64 bits

Comment: I am not the owner of the solution, its legacy project and I cannot change/convert/upgrade versions or etc. I have to work with what I have.
I tried opening just that one project in vs2022 but it also doesn't get loaded.
Regarding the CPU, all the projects are set to run as Any CPU, when opening csproj for editing - no x86/x64 flags there.

Comment: Ok, so that one project is what  you concentrate your efforts on. it not clear why the project would not work in vs2022, but as noted, try setting the project to x32, and see what happens. No use trying to load + deal with 100+ projects when ONE project does not work. Regardless of the 99 projects, you have ONE project that don't work in vs2022, and it should . So, what is the error message and "failed" to load issue then? So, really, this is a question of: "I have ONE  project that don't load or work in vs2022". As I stated, you might be using ANY cpu, but in vs2019, that would be running x32

Comment: I would like to know how to troubleshoot this, how to find the call stack of the error, what exactly leads to this specific error:
"Invalid class string", if this leads to COM, I would like to know which COM, which guid is not found or etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the issue by trying to find guids in the csproj, remove them one by one and then trying to reload the project.

These were two item groups which cause the issue, after removing them, the project was loaded OK.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="XXX\{967B4E0D-AD0C-4609-AB67-0FA40C0206D8}" />
    <Service Include="XXX{C0C07587-41A7-46C8-8FBD-3F9C8EBE2DDC}" />
    <Service Include="{C0C07587-41A7-46C8-8FBD-3F9C8EBE2DDC}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="XXXReporting\{967B4E0D-AD0C-4609-AB67-0FA40C0206D8}" />
    <Service Include="XXXReporting\{C0C07587-41A7-46C8-8FBD-3F9C8EBE2DDC}" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After googling the guids and looking into the project, it seems that the issue is with Crystal Reports which are used in the project.

Its a shame VS doesn't include guid or some context for the error.

Currently I have removed those item groups and everything seems to work OK, so far.

In a meanwhile I found there is a special version of crystal reports for VS 2022, will try it later, I found the info here:
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/3204647
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_21.msi

Comment: I not used crystal reports, but I never needed any GUID's for my projects. But, like always, without details, it hard to debug in the dark. And that removing those GUIDS allows the build is a good start.

Comment: My idea to look for it was like this: if such error happens usually when com class object cannot be created then there should be reference in the project to some com object which uses GUID. I looked for guids trying remove and check if it loads.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some screen shots, we have a wee bit more info.

Try forcing that project to x32, and do a re-build all of that ONE project. That x800 errors often suggests/hints at a bit size miss-match. (in other words, that project has some assembly references that are x32 bits). Also, check the references - are some missing?

So, see/try if you can build by forcing that project as x32 bits. As you note, it build's in vs2019, but not vs2022 - and as I noted, vs2022 is a x64 bit product, and that what's different here.

In fact, open the project in vs2019, force to x32 bits, do a re-build of that one project.

Now, try opening in vs2022, does it load and/or build?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but this was not the case, I have answered my question.